# How To : Wedding Invitation via Email to Colleagues from Different Geographical Location

Tags: professionalism, ethics

The people in question are aware of my wedding and have even congratulated me during one of the team meetings. So it goes without saying that I'm obliged to send them an invitation even though I know well enough that they won't be able to make it due to time constraints.

I'm stuck at deciding what to write in the invitation email. The one thing that seems like a good idea is to put something along the lines of 'I seek your blessings...'. But apart from that I'm completely blank on how to start the email.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a poll about wedding invitations.

Comment: Agreed - the question could be just as easily about friends, not work colleagues, so there's no real Workplace involvement.

Answer (score 3):

It makes no practical sense to issue wedding invitations to people merely because they congratulated you. A note that expresses thanks for their kindness, appreciation for their good will and gratitude for the good luck of having them as co-workers - that note should do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my country is usual to have two types of wedding announcement:

**Wedding announcement**

I believe this is  the best for you. It is simply official info about the wedding:

> John Doe and Marry Unknown
>
> We are pleased to announce you that John Doe and Marry Unknown decided to say YES to their life together "forever after"
>
> Wedding will take place in Bielefeld, Germany on 17th November at 12:00 CET
>
> On behalf of newly-weds, Jane Doe, mother

**Wedding invitation**

> John Doe and Marry Unknown
>
> We are inviting you to our wedding "Simply love" and following wedding party.
>
> This lovely event will take place in Bielefeld, Germany on 17th November at 12:00 CET
>
> Please RVSP by 30th October

I believe your colleagues expect to receive only official "announcement" and not invitation

Comment: Wedding announcements are normally mailed immediately following a wedding and dinner contain details of how to attend... unless you want some of those receiving an announcement to attend.